# Node raises the error cannot lookup view "index" in views directory "views" depending on the current directory in the shell

Tags: node.js, express, directory

So I have been working on my Node.js project and my `index.js` (on my root directory of my project) contains

```js
const server = require("./server/server.js") //listens on port 8080 and other server stuff
```

So when I do `$ cd server` and then do `$ node server.js`, the server runs just fine on port `8080`. **BUT** when I try that on the root directory, `$ node index.js`, It raises the error
`Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"` and then shows that its on `server/server.js`. And this is my code that renders the page:

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

My poorly made file structure:

```
myProject/
|
|--index.js 
|
|--server/
|---server.js
|---views/
|----index.ejs
```

Answer (score 1):

If view directory is not set, you need to specify your views directory in app.js similarly like this,

```
const path = require('path');
app.set('server/views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
```